# Where am I making a mistake in following delta function integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

If the given integral is $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \delta (x-x^{'})f(x)$$ The answer is $f(x')$. However if we make a transformation$$x\rightarrow\alpha x=y$$and $$x^{'}\rightarrow\alpha x^{'}=y^{'}$$ substituting this into the above equation I get$$\alpha dx= dy$$

so the integral becomes, $$\frac{1}{\alpha}\int dy \delta (\frac{y}{\alpha}-\frac{y^{'}}{\alpha})f(\frac{y}{\alpha} )$$ Hence the answer is $$\frac{1}{\alpha}f(\frac{y^{'}}{\alpha})$$

If we go back to the old variables $x$ by making an inverse transformation $$y^{'}=\alpha x^{'}$$ I am getting $$\frac{1}{\alpha}f(x^{'})$$ However the solution is not just $$f(x^{'})$$
Where am I going wrong in the following transformation ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your error lies in assuming that  $$\int \delta(x - b ) f(x) dx = f(b) \implies \int \delta(ax - b ) f(x) dx = f(b/a)$$ i.e. that the delta integral merely "picks the value of the function where the arg of the delta is zero"

Actually scaling the delta argument scales the result.  [In particular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Scaling_and_symmetry), for any $a>0$

$$ \int \delta(ax) dx = \frac{1}{a} $$

and also 
$$ \int\delta(ax - b ) f(x) dx = \frac{1}{a} f(b/a) $$

Hence 
$$
\frac{1}{\alpha}\int dy \delta (\frac{y}{\alpha}-\frac{y^{'}}{\alpha})f(\frac{y}{\alpha} ) = f(\frac{y^{'}}{\alpha})$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.